# Node embeddings and densely connected graphs

Tags: python, graphs, embeddings, graph-neural-network

I have a dataset of users and their interests (represented by categories) and I’m trying to embed the graph which results from connecting users if they have a common interest, so I’ll add an edge for every interest that a person has.

The problem is that for about 38k users I am getting ~ 4M edges and when applying node2vec to the graph and representing it with TSNE I can see that the points are densely distributed inside a circle. This strongly suggests me that the graph is densely connected.

A. Can my last statement be verified by checking that the average node degree is somewhat ‘high’?

B. Do you have any suggestion on how to build the graph in such a way to make communities more evident? (The interests are dynamic)

Thanks!